# Using REGEX to remove all characters between 2 given strings (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say I have a string and a variable,

```
string = '(-500)x^3'
a = 100
```

I want to replace all the characters ONLY within the brackets with the value of a.
Such that the string is returned as,

```
string = '(100)x^3'
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should at least attempt to solve the problem with code and post that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
import re

re.sub(r'\((.*)\)', r'(%s)' %s a,  string)
```

Comment: I changed it up to, re.sub(r'\((.*)\)', r'({0})'.format(a),  string), because your string formatting didn't work for me and it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that formatting is the old one, my bad. Yours is preferable in fact.